# Hand drawn marker recognition with OpenCV 3.2 SVM

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, svm

I work on a project similar to "Inkhunter" mobile application.

In this application they have a simple 
[smile shape marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CI0C.jpg),
this marker is drawn by the user and application predict and track this marker very well.

My question is which algorithm they may be using for recognition and tracking this simple marker.

I've try to achieve this result with OpenCV 3.2 SVM training, but prediction is not good enough.

Comment: ohh, thanks. But i can achieve similar results with SVM training?